# ios get 12AM for today

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[calendar setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Central"]];

NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

[nowComponents setHour:hour];
[nowComponents setMinute:0];
[nowComponents setSecond:0];

NSLog(@"%@", [calendar dateFromComponents:nowComponents]);
```

logs `2012-01-01 06:00:00 +0000`. The time is correct based on the timezone setting, but today is July 20th... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the log from "NSLog(@"%@", today);" ? If so it might to be the date of the iPhone/Simulator that is off... (since the start date is already off)

Comment: @Xval touche. I put that in there from memory which was way off. It's now updated to reflect the real code. +1 for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the year, month, and day components, and construct a new `NSDate`, like this:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[calendar setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Central"]];

NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
today = [calendar dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
```

You do not need to get the time components and then set them back to zero: you can keep them at their defaults by *not* asking to extract them in the first place.

Comment: I'm **assuming** that using `fromDate` uses the month and day from the date passed. After all, I never set the year :|

Comment: It took me a minute to see what you did. Thanks for the clever help :)